# How to make image slide off screen instead of shrink when screen size reduces

Tags: html, css

Currently I have an image that when the screen shrinks, the image shrinks along with it and scrunches up. I realize this is because I have the image height and width set to percentages:

```
 <div class="container1 overlay">
            <img class="fleet" id="hero" src="./images/hero-truck-lg.jpg" alt="Mountain View">
        </div>
#hero {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -35px;
}
```

However, on the website I'm trying to emulate (https://workwave.com/), the image slides off the screen to the left. Since this is a gradual slide, it does not seem to have been accomplished by media queries. However, I am confused how it is accomplished. How can I replicate the image sliding off the screen gradually like the guy holding the phone in the first panel below the nav on this site? https://workwave.com/

Comment: consider background image

Comment: does making it a background image result in it sliding off the screen?

Comment: unline image, a background can overlflow [not the good word] which mean you can see only part of the image. Read more about it and you will understand ;)

Comment: the background-images on this site aren't sliding off the screen though https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_background_multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the site it self

```
.corp-hp--hero {
    position: relative;
    background: url(/images/corporate/hero-truck-lg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 24% 71%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

you can see the image is actually a background for an element NOT an `img` element, also the position of the background is `24% 71%` which means the background will be positioned by a percentage of the view not by a constant value  which will give the shifting impression

Comment: better remove `center center` to avoid confusion as you are overrinding it with background-position later